# Why use CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync and other similar ones in production?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm talking about code in tutorials that looks like this:

```
DatabaseResponse database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);

await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/id");
```

It seems to me that if your app starts and it can't find a database (which should be persistent between app restarts/rollouts), there are bigger problems to worry about and the CreateIfNotExists is kind of meaningless.

Is this anyway a recommended pattern in production?

Comment: There's really no right answer to this. Some apps have all their databases created via DevOps pipeline (and maybe baseline collections as well). Others create them in code. There might also be dynamically-created databases & collections (e.g. new collection for a new customer; no possible way to create that ahead of time). Really this is up to you. Most demo code includes db/collection creation to make sure the demo works (and to keep things simple and not have to build out a build environment).

Comment: Hi, can my answer answer your question?:)

Comment: Yes. I was waiting to see whether any other answers might show up before selecting an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

> It seems to me that if your app starts and it can't find a database
> (which should be persistent between app restarts/rollouts), there are
> bigger problems to worry about and the CreateIfNotExists is kind of
> meaningless.
>
> Is this anyway a recommended pattern in production?

I think it depends on your needs. In general, using `CosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync`can avoid trouble. But if you need to check, you can use another method, such as `CosmosClient.CreateDatabaseAsync` and `CosmosClient.GetDatabase(String)`. `CosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` x is basically a combination of the two. Design some logic, if it does not exist you can get some hints.